# How to use rmagic in Azure Notebooks?

Tags: python, r, azure, jupyter

I am trying to get some data out of R snippet to Azure Python 3 Jupyter notebook (hosting is available for free at http://notebooks.azure.com).

I tried the following in Python 3 notebook:

```
%load_ext rmagic
```

then tried to embed R:

```
%%R -o x
x <- 1
```

then

```
x
```

Here I get Python error: `name 'x' is not defined` – see the picture below. What is the right way to embed R into Python 3 and exchange data using Azure Notebooks?

[Azure Notebooks http://nogin.info/R2Py.png](http://nogin.info/R2Py.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@DmitryNogin, I reproduced the issue successfully. And according to the descprition below from [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/config/extensions/rmagic.html), you need to use `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` instead of `%load_ext rmagic` in jupyter notebook now.

> The rmagic extension has been moved to rpy2 as rpy2.interactive.ipython.

However, I got some other errors below when I tried `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` in notebook.

```
ImportError: libRblas.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I searched a solution which need to set an environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/MR0-3.3.0/R-3.3.0/lib/R/lib` (the path value which I found via the command `which R`) on Azure notebook server. However, the host Ubuntu OS not be installed `vi` or `vim` and I don't know the `sudo` password for `nbuser` in the terminal, so although the solution works for ipython in the terminal of notebook server, it can't make the jupyter works.

My final work solution is that using the terminal of notebook server to command `ln -s /usr/lib64/MR0-3.3.0/R-3.3.0/lib/R/lib/* ~/anaconda3_410/lib/`.

Then, when you enter `%load_ext rpy2.ipython`, you will get an error `ImportError ..../libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC`. You only need to enter `import readline` to solve it before `%load_ext rpy2.ipython`.

Finally, you can load `rpy2.ipython` for `%R xxx` with some warning information.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your second solution but `import readline` gives `ImportError: libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` while `!pip list | grep readline` gives `readline                              6.2.4.1 `